# jquery: dynamically change title (.append()? .html()? or others?)

Tags: jquery, html, image, dynamic, append

I would like to change a title dynamically based on a click I have developed on an image slider. I have tried alert to check my code and each click the alert shows a different name which its supposed to. but when I tried to append() or html() it stays on the first picture name.

```
var src = $('#slides img').attr('src'); 
$("#image").click(function(){
$("#pic-title").html(src); //this shows the first images' name and never changes.
//$("#pic-title").append(src); //this shows the first images' name and adds on each click, but stays the same name and never changes.
});


<div id="pic-title"></div>
```

I would like to change the image name and not have it repeat.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: can you add the html this refers to as well?

Comment: I think thats what you mean by html? I added the div tag that should be referenced to when I output the title name.

Comment: Why are you using the images src attr, why not rel, alt, or title?

Comment: That was just an example to get my point across

Comment: I suppose a lot of people do use the file name as a sort of title, just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're storing the `src` variable before the user ever clicks on an image, so it's always going to be the same.  Put the `var src` inside your click function:

```
$("#image").click(function(){
    var src = this.src;
    $("#pic-title").text(src);
});
```